# What form of zinc's found naturally in vegetables & meat?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

What kind of zinc naturally occurs in plants? Zinc oxide, zinc sulphide, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely form is $\ce {Zn^{2+}}$ bound inside a protein, or maybe chelated to some amino acids. It is not very likely that there is zinc oxide, or zinc sulfide, or zinc sulfate in organic matter.

Answer (score -1):

Different vegetables contain different types of Zinc compounds, so we can't say specifically which type of zinc compound is there in vegetables.

Zinc Oxide is the most used supplement in the U.S.

Zinc carbonate is also present, which our body cannot absorb.

Also they can contain  zinc picolinate, zinc gluconate or zinc citrate (zinc picolinate is better than zinc gluconate.), zinc glycinate, etc.

---

Reference: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc#Dietary_intake)

Comment: I don't know why this was flagged VLQ, but since I am here: I believe with "types of zinc" you are referring to the variety of zinc compounds present/possible.

Comment: @Martin yes I have tried to list "types of zinc" and I think that is what OP want!

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. I just wanted to clarify, before upvoting, that's all. I don't think your answer deserves a downvote and not a flag either.

Comment: @Martin I know it is not perfect(not so bad that it should be flagged). This type of question can only answered by some experts. Though I have tried to give answer from stuff I have read at different places.

Comment: I polished a little the language, please check. (roll back if you think i made a mistake) As I said, I don't think it deserves a downvote and I have no idea why it was flagged